# .html Pages not working in IIS 7.5 (64 Bit OS)

Tags: windows-7, iis-7.5, 64-bit

I create a Web  application on my 32 BIT OS (Windows XP) and then i successfully add this WEB Application to IIS 7 on Windows 7 (64 Bit) on my Friend's PC.

Since .aspx pages are randering fine but .html pages are not randering in Windows 7 (64 Bit).

Since  I have also added `Handler Mapping` in my Windows 7 PC, but with no luck

[image]

I get this error when i tried to hit .html page on windows 7 PC

[image]

Since i tried this solution 
[IIS 7.5 doesn't load static html pages](https://serverfault.com/questions/271501/iis-7-5-doesnt-load-static-html-pages) , but i can't able to find "feature" - Role Services (as answered by Vlad)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vlad's answer on the question you reference is relevant to Server 2008, not Windows 7.

In Windows 7, you need to go into  `Programs and Features`, into Windows Features and enable the Static Content feature:

I would remove the script mapping you created before doing that.

[image]